# configure sendmail for php email()

Tags: sendmail

Recently I installed sendmail in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig
```

When I try to send mail using php `email();` function to send email

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mail Test at ".strftime("%T", time());
$message = "This is a test.";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$from = "anotheremail@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: {$from}";
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $result ? "sent" : "error";
```

Now when I browse the php site I get sent message but I don't get email (in my official email).
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add your hostname to `/etc/hosts` (find the line with `127.0.0.1` and append your hostname):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain your_hostname_here
```

Try restarting `apache`:

```
$> sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Please keep in mind that:

1. `mail` returns success (`true`) if it transported your mail successfully to the configured MTA. This does not mean, that your MTA actually sent any mail.
2. modern mail servers might not accept your email, since spam filters (dns lookup, sender verification, ...) might be active and prevent delivery.

You can check `sendmail`s mail queue anytime with the command

```
$> mailq
```